# Backspace and browser navigation

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, outlook-web-access

Usually when an input is focused the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key doesn't executes the browser's history back function.

But it began to happen in the compose input field of Outlook Web Access when using Google Chrome 7.0.517 in Windows 7

How to prevent this?

Comment: Is your question How to stop this? Or Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this extension for Chrome: [BackspaceMeansBackspace - 1.2](http://www.chromeextensions.org/appearance-functioning/backspacemeansbackspace/)

Comment: I was just about to post a similar question, although mine included Firefox as well: How to stop the backspace key from sending a "back" command in a web browser. This is easier than remapping keys, and it works fine under Win7! Thanks, @Sahil.